# Gottox socket.io-java-client "Error while handshaking" null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io to connect to a streaming server hosted by [Geoloqi](https://community.geoloqi.com/discussion/75/viewing-real-time-group-location-in-a-map-using-ios-sdk/p1)

I grabbed the Gottox socket.io-java-client code straight from github and didn't make any modifications, except to change the url, but it's giving me the "Error while handshaking" message. The url should work as I got it from the makers of Geoloqi: https://community.geoloqi.com/discussion/19/data-streaming#Item_11 (see the 1st response).

Here is the code, from BasicExample.java

```
package basic;
/*
 * socket.io-java-client Test.java
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Enno Boland
 * socket.io-java-client is a implementation of the socket.io protocol in Java.
 * 
 * See LICENSE file for more information
 */
import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class BasicExample implements IOCallback {
    private SocketIO socket;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new BasicExample();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BasicExample() throws Exception {
        socket = new SocketIO();
//      socket.connect("http://localhost:8080/", this);
        socket.connect("https://subscribe.geoloqi.com:443", this);

        // Sends a string to the server.
        socket.send("Hello Server");

        // Sends a JSON object to the server.
        socket.send(new JSONObject().put("key", "value").put("key2",
                "another value"));

        // Emits an event to the server.
        socket.emit("event", "argument1", "argument2", 13.37);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
an Error occured
io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking
    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:322)
    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$7(IOConnection.java:292)
    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:199)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.socket.IOConnection.handshake(IOConnection.java:302)
    ... 2 more
May 1, 2013 10:02:49 PM io.socket.IOConnection cleanup
INFO: Cleanup
```

What's going wrong with the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/blob/master/src/io/socket/IOConnection.java) where the exception is coming from (`IOConnection.java:302`, from the inner `NullPointerException`), there's this block of code:

```
if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection) connection)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
}
```

Clearly `connection` must be non-null, otherwise it wouldn't pass the `instanceof` test.  Therefore, `sslContext` must be null.  Since the only other places in that file that `sslContext` is referenced is in `setSslContext()` and `getSslContext()`, the only logical conclusion is that **you must call `setSslContext()` prior to making an SSL connection**.  `SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()` also calls through to `IOConnection.setSslContext()`, so you can call that too instead.

Try this:

```
SocketIO.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());
socket = new SocketIO();
socket.connect("https://subscribe.geoloqi.com:443", this);
...
```

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield hi sir, i have same problem and i can not find any body to help me, please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763858/android-get-an-error-while-handshaking-for-socket thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client to create my Java client. Seems like my server was based on 1.X and this only supports 1.0 (https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/issues/101). Solved by using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java instead.